# Slick-Slider initialize as fast as possible - don't wait for $(document).ready(function($)

Tags: javascript, slick.js

We load the Slick slider 1.8.1 via "defer" attribute in the header section.

```
<script defer src="https://domain.xyz/templates/js/slick.min.js"></script>
```

We want the slider to be built as fast as possible - so ideally we want to have the Slick slider initialize as soon as the products for the slider (application is an online shop) are loaded in the DOM.

In the examples for initializing the slick slider, they always do it when EVERYTHING is loaded via

```
$(document).ready(function($){

    $('.myslider').slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: false,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        responsive: [
            {
              breakpoint: 1024,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 4,
                slidesToScroll: 3,
                infinite: true,
                dots: true
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 700,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3,
                slidesToScroll: 2
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 480,
              settings: {
                slidesToShow: 2,
                slidesToScroll: 1
              }
            }
        ]
    });
    
});
```

But we don't want to wait for document.ready since there is plenty of content to load after the first slider and we want to have it displayed as fast as possible.

Comment: If you want to use `defer`, then only `DOMContentLoaded` makes sense as trigger for this, I think. You can not just initialize it by calling the method the slider elements in the DOM, because you can't be sure the script has already loaded by then. For that, you would have to embed it without defer.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I've modified the slick.js file and put this statement at the very end (after the normal slick.js code):

```
(function () {
    var evt = document.createEvent("Event");
    evt.initEvent("slickLoaded",true,true);
    document.dispatchEvent(evt);
})();
```

I've then created an Event Listener for that event:

```
<script>
   document.addEventListener("slickLoaded", function() {
      console.log('slick was loaded');
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

make slick slider display:none using css and then display block when document ready.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I concern, never edit the core page. The best is to find another solution. Hope someone can put solution

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33866931)